# sudo apt-get purge firefox not working in batch file

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I have a simple shell script that is used for updating Firefox. The content of it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo apt-get pruge firefox

sudo apt-get install firefox
```

That's all it is. Now, when I run the file in terminal, using in order,

```
cd Desktop/Batch\ Files

sudo chmod 775 Firefox.sh

sudo ./Firefox.sh
```

The output says that the `pruge` action cannot be completed but the rest of the file runs.

Here is the exact output:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection timed out
E: Invalid operation pruge
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version (57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 261 not upgraded.
```

As annoying as it is, I can still run the code, line by line, and the `purge` action works.

Comment: You should choose an answer which was helpful and accept it, see [/help/someone-answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: For updating Firefox, `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y firefox` should be sufficient. You have been removing it, then reinstalling it.

Comment: Anyway this is not a `batch file` it's a shell script ;)

Answer (score 10):

You have a typo in your script, it should be `purge` and not `pruge`. And up to that you not need sudo inside your script if you call your script with `sudo script.sh`. So your script should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get purge firefox
apt-get install firefox
```

You want to put the `-y` flag on the install to make it automatically install even if there are multiple packages to install. So change:

```
apt-get install firefox
```

into:

```
apt-get install -y firefox
```

If you however want the output to be silent you can use the `-qq` option (which implies `-y`), in that case you as well need to give the purge the `-y` or `-qq` option too but then both commands will run silently. Example of a completely silent script:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get purge -qq firefox &&
apt-get install -qq firefox
```

You surely wonder why I have put those `&&` into the script: this causes the second command only to run if the first was successful.

However normally it is not needed to purge Firefox, for installing a new version. A simply `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` should suffice for that, since the profile and settings are not getting purged anyways.

Comment: I might need to look over my work next time, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your code you put "pruge" it needs to be changed to "purge".

Comment: Right, I might need to look over my work more careful next time. I look all over and didn't see that. Thanks!